# Add thousand comma separators to input type number

Tags: javascript, html, numbers, separator

I have this script that another member of StackOverflow made but I need to put a comma separator for thousands numbers.

How I can do that?

```js
(function($) {
  $.fn.currencyInput = function() {
    this.each(function() {
      var wrapper = $("<div class='currency-input' />");
      $(this).wrap(wrapper);
      $(this).before("<span class='currency-symbol'>$</span>");
      $(this).change(function() {
        var min = parseFloat($(this).attr("min"));
        var max = parseFloat($(this).attr("max"));
        var value = this.valueAsNumber;
        if(value < min)
          value = min;
        else if(value > max)
          value = max;
        $(this).val(value.toFixed(2)); 
      });
    });
  };
})(jQuery);

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input.currency').currencyInput();
});
```

```css
.currency {
  padding-left:12px;
}

.currency-symbol {
  position:absolute;
  padding: 2px 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" class="currency" min="0.01" max="2500.00" value="25.00" />
```

Comment: Number inputs do not have commas so that seems like it will have issues. But did you look at other answers on stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901102/how-to-print-a-number-with-commas-as-thousands-separators-in-javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You can't put commas on a "number" input, so change it to "text".
2. Since you can't use "toLocaleString" and toFixed together, a different solution is needed:

```js
(function($) {
  $.fn.currencyInput = function() {
    this.each(function() {
      var wrapper = $("<div class='currency-input' />");
      $(this).wrap(wrapper);
      $(this).before("<span class='currency-symbol'>$</span>");
      $(this).val(parseFloat($(this).val()).toLocaleString(undefined, {minimumFractionDigits:2, maximumFractionDigits:2}));
      
      $(this).change(function() {
        var min = parseFloat($(this).attr("min"));
        var max = parseFloat($(this).attr("max"));

        var value = parseFloat($(this).val().replace(/,/g, ''));
        if(value < min)
          value = min;
        else if(value > max)
          value = max;
        $(this).val(value.toLocaleString(undefined, {minimumFractionDigits:2, maximumFractionDigits:2})); 
      });
    });
  };
})(jQuery);

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input.currency').currencyInput();
});
```

```css
.currency {
  padding-left:12px;
}

.currency-symbol {
  position:absolute;
  padding: 2px 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="currency" min="0.01" max="2500.00" value="1125.00" />
```

Comment: Great thumbs Up!

Comment: how to change this to dot separator?

Comment: @SoniSilalahi After running the toLocaleString, you can replace the comma to whatever you want

`$(this).val(parseFloat($(this).val()).toLocaleString(undefined, {minimumFractionDigits:2, maximumFractionDigits:2}).replace(/,/g, "."));`

`$(this).val(value.toLocaleString(undefined, {minimumFractionDigits:2, maximumFractionDigits:2}).replace(/,/g, "."));`